# Class 'CI_Upload' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some wierd issue. On live, my site is running with no issue. I am running it on XAMPP to perform some changes.

But on XAMPP, i am having following issue.

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Upload' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\hm360\application\libraries\upload.php on line 3
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>   Message: Class 'CI_Upload' not found
>   Filename: libraries/upload.php
>   Line Number: 3

Please guide. Same code working perfectly on live.

```
<?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class SellYourProperty extends CI_Controller {  

        public function index()  
        {  
            $this->load->view("baby_form_add");  
        }  

        function savingdata()  
        {  
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $data['title'] = 'Multiple file upload';

            $config = array(
                'upload_path' => './uploads/',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png'
            );

            // load Upload library
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

and upload.php code in libraries folder

    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Upload extends CI_Upload
    {
        public $multi = 'all';
```

Comment: At the moment I can only get something close to your code to work if I autoload the upload library. If I don't  CI_Upload is not findable ( as per your error).  Now that is strange... I should add I renamed your Upload to Uploads to make it different to the CI_Upload whose filename is also Upload. That also makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So reconstructing your error...

application/libraries/Upload.php

```
class Upload extends CI_Upload {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        echo "Hi I am the Upload Library Class";
    }
}
```

And the test Controller

```
/**
 * Class Welcome
 *
 * @property CI_Loader   load
 * @property CI_Upload upload
 *
 */
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Results in the Error you are seeing...

If you look for the CI_Upload you will see it is called /system/libraries/Upload.php which is kind of ( if not exactly ) the same name.

So renaming your Upload.php to Uploads.php to make it different results in

**application/libraries/Uploads.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Uploads
 *
 * @property CI_Upload Upload
 */

require_once './system/libraries/Upload.php'; // This is not auto loaded

class Uploads extends CI_Upload {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "Hi I am the Upload Library Class";
    }
}
```

I could get it to work without the require_once using the libraries autoload in config/autoload.php which indicated that the CI Uploads File is not accessible until it is loaded via require_once.